# Python cant pass value out from function

Tags: python, variables

I am having this code as follow where it will get the reply from a device. The value will be compared and the "state" will change accordingly. However, the "state" within the closure function "netcat" couldn't be passed to the "login" function. I have tried to set it to global variable but it doesn't work or may be I don't know the right way to declare it. It end up showing "lala" all the time regardless of the terminal actually showing "user" as the state. How should I solve this?

```
@cherrypy.expose
def login (self, **data):
    passcode = data.get("passcode", None)
    print "logging in using passcode %s"%passcode ,type(passcode)

    import socket
    import time
    state="lala"
    def netcat(content):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(('10.0.0.27', 1001))
        s.sendall(content)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

        while 1:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            if data == "":
                break
            print "Received:", repr(data)
            data1= repr(data)
        print data1
        if "LU" in data1:
            if not "00" in data1:
                if "FE" in data1:
                    state="engineer"
                else: 
                    state="user"
            else:
                    state="none"
        else:
            state="unknown"
        print state
        time.sleep(1)
        return state #this will show the right value
        print "Connection closed."
        s.close()

    netcat ("\x03LI%s\x0D"%passcode)
    return state #this will always show "lala"
```

Comment: `return netcat("\x03LI%s\x0D"%passcode)`

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the definitions of netcat and of login (thanks mhlester), include the line:

```
global state
```

Otherwise, `state` is treated as a local variable whose value is ignored/destroyed once netcat completes.

Alternatively, and probably better, you can replace the second to last line with:

```
state = netcat ("\x03LI%s\x0D"%passcode)
```

This works because netcat has `state` as its return value (netcat ends with the line "return state").

In the comments, Petr Joachim points out another issue with this code:

```
    return state #this will show the right value
    print "Connection closed."
    s.close()
```

Nothing in the netcat function is executed after the return statement.  If you want to close `s`, you need to reorder:

```
    print "Connection closed."
    s.close()
    return state #this will show the right value
```

Comment: And by the way, do not close socket (`s.close()`) after calling `return state`

Comment: for your first solution, `global state` needs to be included in both netcat __and__ login. But the return is definitely the better solution

Comment: Yes the `return state` works now! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

`login` and `netcat` both declare their own local `state`. You'll need to add

```
global state
```

to the beginning of **both** of those functions for it to work.

You currently `return` the state, but it isn't stored anywhere. Instead you're setting it, but currently only locally.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using globals, i'd recommend you to make use of the returned value of `netcat`:

```
state = netcat ("\x03LI%s\x0D"%passcode)
```

Using globals often cause confusion about which function change a variable. This is much cleaner and easier to read.

Also, when you use the `return` statement, the function quits. So `s.close()` wouldn't be called. Put the `return` at the end of your function:

```
s.close()
print "Connection closed."
return state #this will show the right value
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! That clarifies a lot!